# Error Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be PATH

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just started on Selenium and was able to load up google but now when I run the following code it produces the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message 'chromedriver' executable needs
to be PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Why is it saying "C:Users/Colin/Python/chromedriver" is not a path?

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:Users/Colin/Python/chromedriver")
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 6):

While working with *Selenium v3.x*, *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* you may need to pass the argument `executable_path` along with the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary through  either of the following options:

- Double back slashes i.e. `(\\)`
- Single back slash i.e `(\)` along with the raw `(r)` switch.
- Binary extension i.e. `(.exe)`

So you have to change the line :

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:Users/Colin/Python/chromedriver")
```

With :

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Colin\Python\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to add the executable path everytime you want to use the chrome driver, you can just move the chromedriver.exe file to the same current working directory