# chromedriver.exe is in PATH, but selenium gives me an error

Tags: python, bash, selenium, windows-10, python-2.x

I'm using the bash shell in Windows 10 which makes everything feel like a unix system and I'm trying to run the following python2.7 code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

However, I get the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "seleniumtest.py", line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
File "/home/eirik/.local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/eirik/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

By googeling I found that this was a quite common problem and that I had to download the chromedriver and specifiy where it was. So I changed the above to this:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```

But I got the same result. After that I went into Windows Enviroment Variable and made sure that the folder where I put the chromedriver was read as PATH. It was.

To check if this PATH was also read by the bash shell, I wrote the following:

```
    echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | nl
```

In my bash shell. This gave the output:

```
 1  /home/eirik/bin
 2  /home/eirik/.local/bin
 3  /usr/local/sbin
 4  /usr/local/bin
 5  /usr/sbin
 6  /usr/bin
 7  /sbin
 8  /bin
 9  /usr/games
10  /usr/local/games
11  /mnt/c/webdriver
12  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common
13  /mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
14  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client
15  /mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client
16  /mnt/c/Windows/System32
17  /mnt/c/Windows
18  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
19  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
20  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin
21  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone
22  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
23  /mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL
24  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
25  /mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT
26  /mnt/c/Windows/System32
27  /mnt/c/Windows
28  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem
29  /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
30  /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
31  /mnt/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64
32  /mnt/c/Users/Hauge/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
33  /snap/bin
34  /mnt/c/webdriver/
```

Where /mnt/c/webdriver/ is where the chromedriver.exe file is located. I am at a loss to what to do next. I have tried everything I could find, but I can't seem to get selenium to accept my chromedriver. Does anybody have any idea of what to do?

Comment: this statement `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'/path/to/chromedriver.exe')` should work without adding to **Environment Variables**, did you use the full path? IE. if it's located under C: you use `C:\My\Chrome\Path\Chromedriver.exe`.

Comment: Yeah. I tried both having the driver in the same folder and just writing the filename as well as writing out the entire path.

Comment: When you pass the full path, it gives you the exact same `Traceback`?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path) as well, in case you are having trouble passing the path in the correct format.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I have tried your last tip and I get the same error as above, but with this part changed: Message: 'C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!
By putting the chromedriver.exe file in the same folder as the script and running it with ./chromedriver.exe the script was able to access it from that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are trying to have your Ubuntu subsystem access a Windows driver when it needs a Linux driver. Download the chromedriver for linux64 and ensure that it is in your path.

Comment: This may very well be the solution to the problem. However, I can't test it as my solution makes the script work. But I think this would have been a better way to do it.