# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions with Selenium and ChromeDriver 77.0

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

And this is an error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/project/Python/TEST_selenium/chromedriver_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions
```

I can't figure out why an error occurs in this simple code.

This code worked a month ago. But it doesn't work now.

I've updated both chrome and chrome drivers but that doesn't fix the problem.

My chrome and chrome driver version is 77.

Comment: .exe is required since you are on a Windows machine, be sure to have downloaded the Windows chromedriver binaries and not the Linux ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

From your question, I would guess that your selenium version is out of date. I believe that going to Chrome driver 77 updated the launch behaviour.

Try `pip install -U selenium` and see if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your ChromeDriver.exe to the folder where you have the project or try only `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: unrecognized capability: chromeOptions
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session due to unrecognized `chromeOptions`.

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- If you intent to pass the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver*, you have to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver*.

  > You can find a detailed discussion in [WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH while setting UserAgent through Selenium Chromedriver Phyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091420/webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-while/50094553#50094553)
- As you are on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) system, you need to specify the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* binary through  either of the following options :

  - Double back slashes i.e. `(\\)`
  - Single back slash i.e `(\)` along with the raw `(r)` switch.
  - Binary extension i.e. `(.exe)`

    > You can find a detailed discussion in [Error Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path/49201386#49201386)

Your working code will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com')
```