# set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O) with ChromeDriver Selenium CeleryPython

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, celery

I initialized a webdriver object with celery but reported this error on windows.

```
set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)
```

Code trial:

```
celery_app = Celery()
celery_app.config_from_object('config.celeryconfig')
from celery import Task
from selenium import webdriver
eventlet.monkey_patch(os=False)



class GetDriver(Task):
    test = 'test'
    chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

@celery_app.task(base=GetDriver, bind=True)
def demo(self, params):
    print(params)
    print(self.test)
```

Can cellery initialize a webdriver object at initialization?

Answer (score 0):

```
celery_app = Celery()
celery_app.config_from_object('config.celeryconfig')
from celery import Task
from selenium import webdriver
eventlet.monkey_patch(os=False)



class GetDriver(Task):
    test = 'test'
    chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

@celery_app.task(base=GetDriver, bind=True)
def demo(self, params):
    print(params)
    print(self.test)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)
```

...is observed when the [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) interpreter is unable to locate the **ChromeDriver** binary while trying to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

In your code block you have used:

```
chromedriver_path = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

Your program is unable to locate the **chromedriver.exe**. Hence the error.

---

### Solution

You need to mention the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
chromedriver_path = r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl/46089751#46089751)
- [WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH while setting UserAgent through Selenium Chromedriver Phyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091420/webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-while/50094553#50094553)
- [Error Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path/49201386#49201386)

---

### Outro

[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the parameter "-P eventlet" when starting the "celery" service. I encountered the same problem, and then I removed the parameter and the problem was solved.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info  -P eventlet   （old）
celery -A proj worker -l info
```