# Chromedriver needs to be available in the path set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() error with ChromeDriver Selenium Celery Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, celery, celery-task

I set up a celery environment and released two tasks. One is to open Google Chrome, and the other is a simple addition calculation. There is no problem with the function of addition calculation, but the function of opening the browser reports an error, and the browser cannot be opened.

**The error：**

> File
>   "d:\software\professional\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 95, in start
>       (os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message, str(e))) WebDriverException: Message: The executable chromedriver needs to be
>   available in the path. Please see
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
>   set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method
>   (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl8KY.png)

**my code：（tasks.py）**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import time
from proj.celery import app
import os


@app.task
def chrome_test():
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver_path1 = r"chromedriver"  
    driver_path2 = os.path.join(r"D:\SoftWare\Professional\ChromeDriver", "chromedriver.exe")

    # print "try to open chrome..."
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path1, options=chrome_options)
    # executable_path=driver_path, options=chrome_options
    print "open chrome success"
    driver.get("https://www.baidu.com/")
    time.sleep(1)
    print driver
    driver.close()
    return "success to open chrome..."


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x+y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    chrome_test()
```

But if I run the function alone, it can work very well.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
File "d:\software\professional\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 95, in start (os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message, str(e))) 
WebDriverException: Message: The executable chromedriver needs to be available in the path. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home set_nonblocking() on a file object with no setblocking() method (Windows pipes don't support non-blocking I/O)
```

...implies that your program was unable to locate the **ChromeDriver** while trying to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

In your code block you have used:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path1, options=chrome_options)
```

Where,

```
driver_path1 = r"chromedriver"
```

Hence, your program can't locate the **chromedriver.exe**.

---

### Solution

You need to mention the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\SoftWare\Professional\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

Alternatively, using `os.path.join()` you can use:

```
driver_path2 = os.path.join(r"D:\SoftWare\Professional\ChromeDriver", "chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path2, options=chrome_options)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl/46089751#46089751)
- [WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH while setting UserAgent through Selenium Chromedriver Phyton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091420/webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-while/50094553#50094553)
- [Error Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path/49201386#49201386)

---

### tl; dr

[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tested it according to your solution, but it still doesn't work.  Because executing this function alone can load the browser, I suspect it is caused by "celery" incompatibility.

Comment: @Janebook Not sure about loading of the browser through Celery. My answer was to address the current error _...The executable chromedriver needs to be available in the path..._ which you were facing as per the question.

Comment: @Janebook Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I was add the parameter "-P eventlet" when starting the "celery" service. I encountered this problem, and then I removed the parameter and the problem was solved.

```
celery -A proj worker -l info  -P eventlet   （old）
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

I suspect there is a threading issue between windows and "-P eventlet" and celery. The specific reason is not clear.