# Selenium changing default download directory on mac catalina always ends in Error

Tags: selenium, directory, download, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium works fine. The whole script is working good. Now i wanted to change the default download directory like this.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : '/Users/admin/Desktop/spearmint-vector-student-code/Final_Project/daily_stock_data'}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

My chromedriver exec is in the folder

```
/Users/admin/Desktop/spearmint-vector-student-code/Final_Project
```

I always get the following error message.

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201281/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-path You need to put the executeable in chrome.

Comment: looks like it can't find the chrome driver executable, nothing to do with the download directory